# Powershell "forgets" accessing UNC path after Start-Process has been executed

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a very strange behaviour in my powershell script:

```powershell
$env:SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS = 1

$path = "FileSystem::\\some_server\share\Build-Agent-Tools"

# If $path would be a local path, the very last line (UNC access) would never fail
$runtime = "$path\dotnet-runtime-2.2.8-win-x64.exe"

$res = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $runtime -ArgumentList "/install /passive /norestart" -PassThru


@(Get-ChildItem -Path $path ) # This says $path not found, what?!!
```

What I do: I pick a dotnet-runtime installer from a given UNC path and install it on my machine. Then I do a Get-ChildItem on the same UNC path I picked the runtime executable and I get this error:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\some_server\share\Build-Agent-Tools' because it does not exist.
At D:\Untitled1.ps1:11 char:3
+ @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path ) # This says $path not found, what?!!
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\some_server\share\Build-Agent-Tools:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Other executables did not produce such issues. Also calling the runtime executable from a *non UNC* path and then executing the same `Get-ChildItem` code above on the same path works.

What can happen in this cases?

I also found out that inserting a `Start-Sleep 5` *after* `Start-Process` and before the failing `Get-ChildItem` does **sometimes** help. Sometimes 5 seconds failed, sometimes 10 seconds worked.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not a complete solution but I added a helper method, that can wait for the path to become ready

```
function Wait-For-Path-Ready($path) {
    echo "Waiting for '$path' be ready"
    $tries = 100
    $waitInMs = 100
    $success = $false

    for ($i = 0; $i -le $tries; ++$i) {
        try {

            Get-ChildItem $path -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
            $success = $true
            break;

        }
        catch {
            echo "Path not ready, retrying"
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $waitInMs
        }
    }

    if( $success )
    {
        echo "Path is ready"
    }
    else {
        throw "$path failed to become ready after $($tries*$waitInMs / 1000) seconds"
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Wait-For-Path-Ready "somepath`
```